# (..) You should have stopped your car and come/came?(..)

Tags: conditional-constructions

> if you had seen me, you should have stopped your car and come to help me.

Is the above sentence correct or do I need to replace *come* with came?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is correct. Since the sentence has '**should have**' followed by a verb the verb should be in the V3 form or the past participle of come which is 'come'.    An example could be- You should have stopped your car at the shop and looked outside to see me.

Comment: P.S.I would be thankful if you could let me know the name of the book your posted questions are from.

Comment: Plint to Paramount ;)